# ElasticSearch Search for Field Values does not return

Tags: java, elasticsearch, liferay

Lets say I have document in the Elastic Search which does containt field "provider" in the _source.

I have tryied many queries but none of them seem to return the document with searched value.

Doc:

```
"_source" : {
      "jobs" : [ ],
      "provider" : {
        "id" : "1",
        "name" : "Coursera"
      },
      "sckLevels" : [ ],
      "scks" : [ ],
      "trArea" : [ ],
      "trElems" : [ ],
      "training" : {
        "description" : "Cyber sec desc",
        "id" : "0",
        "img" : "img link",
        "link" : "https://google.com",
        "name" : "Cyber sec",
        "trainingProvID" : "1"
      }
```

And my code for the query is:

```
SearchRequest searchRequest = new SearchRequest(index);
    SearchSourceBuilder sourceBuilder = new SearchSourceBuilder();
    sourceBuilder.query(QueryBuilders.termQuery("provider", "Coursera"));
    searchRequest.source(sourceBuilder);
this.multiRequest.add(searchRequest);
```

My response is blank.

Thank you.

Comment: Note: Always provide your mapping, sample documents and expected results while asking ES question, but there are few issues mentioned in my answer please fix them and it should work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is definitely few issues with your Elasticsearch query

1. Seems `provider` field is of object or nested  type, while in your query you are just mentioning `Coursera` but it should be matched against the `name` subfield of `provider` field and based on object or nested data type, you need to modify your query.
2. You are using the `term query` which is not analyzed and used for keyword ie extact match while if your `name` field is defined as `text` it would be lowercased at index time and `Coursera` with captial `C` won't match, you need to use the `match` query on text fields.

Answer (score 1):

thank you, nesting was the problem. I thought that it will do the search on the object.

Came across good thread.

Solved it like this:

```
SearchRequest searchRequest = new SearchRequest(index);
    SearchSourceBuilder sourceBuilder = new SearchSourceBuilder();
    sourceBuilder.query(QueryBuilders.matchQuery("provider.name", "Coursera"));
    searchRequest.source(sourceBuilder);

    this.multiRequest.add(searchRequest);
```